# Time and space complexity of my solution in JS to LeetCode 451. Sort Characters By Frequency

Tags: time-complexity, space-complexity

Might be a silly question to ask on here but preparing for interviews and they ask for time and space complexity so wanted to make sure I got this right.

**The problem is:**

Given a string s, sort it in decreasing order based on the frequency of the characters. The frequency of a character is the number of times it appears in the string.
Return the sorted string. If there are multiple answers, return any of them.

Example 1:
Input: s = "tree"
Output: "eert"
Explanation: 'e' appears twice while 'r' and 't' both appear once.
So 'e' must appear before both 'r' and 't'. Therefore "eetr" is also a valid answer.

Example 2:
Input: s = "cccaaa"
Output: "aaaccc"
Explanation: Both 'c' and 'a' appear three times, so both "cccaaa" and "aaaccc" are valid answers.
Note that "cacaca" is incorrect, as the same characters must be together.

Example 3:
Input: s = "Aabb"
Output: "bbAa"
Explanation: "bbaA" is also a valid answer, but "Aabb" is incorrect.
Note that 'A' and 'a' are treated as two different characters.

**My solution is:**

```
var frequencySort = function(s) {
    //keep a charDict of the chars and frequency 
    //use Object.entries(charDict) to return a 2D array with char and freq
    //use .sort() to sort by frequency (decrementing)
    //return, via map over the sorted array, char.repeat(freq)  
    
    let charDict = {}
    
    for(let char of s){
        if(charDict[char]){
            charDict[char] ++
        }
        else {
            charDict[char] = 1
        }
    }
    
    const sortedArr = Object.entries(charDict)
                        .sort(([,a],[,b]) => b-a)

    return sortedArr.map(([char, freq]) => char.repeat(freq)).join('')
};
```

My assumption is that time complexity is O(n*logn) => because of .sort(([,a],[,b]) => b-a)

and space complexity is O(1) => not sure about this because haven't quite figured out how to calculate space complexity but can't see why space would increase as n increases.